# Tool for automating the testing of CLI applications

Tags: automated-testing, tool-recommend

At my job we have a few products that include command line applications with no GUI alternative.
In the QA team, we are trying to automate more of our regression testing. We've found and started using a tool for our UI products (TestCafe), but I'm struggling to find a good tool to use for CLI testing.

Is anyone able to recommend an appropriate and reputable tool for automating the testing of interactive CLI apps on Windows?

Comment: Which operating system are you working with? I know Windows Command is rather opaque even to the big-box automation tools, but I couldn't begin to make suggestions for anything Mac or *nix based. You may have few options outside of batch scripts or powershell scripts (Windows).

Comment: We run our tests against Windows Server 2016/2019/2022, so a tool for any one of those OS's would be fine

Comment: A quick websearch turns up https://www.coronys.com/how-to-automate-windows-command-line-operations - I have no idea how good or otherwise they might be.